# Getting data by a particular key

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, entity

I am a beginner in java spring boot and I want to find a country by id but it's giving me this error when I test it in Postman meanwhile a country with the said id 4 exist in MySQL daabase. I don't know what went wrong "timestamp": "2022-05-11T16:54:40.909+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"path": "/country/findById/4"

```
Here is my Entity class


@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String capital;
    private String description;
    private String nationality;
    private String continent;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }

    public void setCapital(String capital) {
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getContinent() {
        return continent;
    }

    public void setContinent(String continent) {
        this.continent = continent;
    }

    public List<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<State> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    private List<State> states;
}

Here is my Repository

@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country,Integer> {
}

Here is my Service

@Service
public class CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    public List<Country> getAllCountry() {
        return countryRepository.findAll();
    }
    public void saveCountryInfo(Country country){
        countryRepository.save(country);
    }
    public Optional<Country> getCountryById(Integer id){
        return countryRepository.findById(id);
    }
}

Here is my Controller

@Controller
public class CountryController {
    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    
    @GetMapping("/countries")
    public String getCountry(Model model){
        List<Country> countryList = countryService.getAllCountry();
        model.addAttribute("countries",countryList);

        return "country";
    }
   @PostMapping("/countries/addNew")
    public String saveInfo(Country country){
        countryService.saveCountryInfo(country);
        return "redirect:/countries";
    }
    @GetMapping("/country/findById")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Country> getCountryById(Integer id){
        return countryService.getCountryById(id);
    }
}

But this is the error from postman

"timestamp": "2022-05-11T16:54:40.909+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/country/findById/4"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you are not accepting the id as path variable

```java
 @GetMapping("/country/findById/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Country> getCountryById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){ //Bind PathVariable id to id
        return countryService.getCountryById(id);
    }
```

`{xyz}` this works as placeholder/variable

`@PathVariable("xyz") Integer id` This is how Spring will bind that variable to your parameter

Comment: I have update it with the path variable but now getting this error from postman

Comment: "timestamp": "2022-05-11T17:50:46.415+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/country/findById/4"

Comment: This error has to do with your implementation. Can post your stack trace from your IDE

Comment: These are the error in the IDE

Comment: [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid Object Id definition for `com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country`: cannot find property with name '@id'] with root cause

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid Object Id definition for `com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country`: cannot find property with name '@id'

Comment: In your Entity @Id is coming from javax.persistence.Id?

Comment: Yes, it's from that package